# How to determine whether a spread-sheet cell contains a date, or a real number?

Tags: java, date, cell, apache-poi, poi-hssf

When a cell in a spreadsheet contains a simple date (mm/dd/yyyy) the poi API flags the cell-type as 'numeric'. This is probably because spreadsheets ( IMO ) historically recognize only strings and real numbers.

It is possible to  hard-code the cell-index, and use it conditionally to call 'getDateCellValue'. But this feels like a hack.

What other ways are there in the poi API to determine whether the content in a cell is a Date rather than a real number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the [Getting the Cell Contents section](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) of the [HSSF Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)